# Internet explorer cancels ajax requests

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vue.js

I am making a request to the server through Ajax -Jquery, this request returns more than 2000 records (about 16,000 records)

In google chrome executed the call although it took about 40 seconds but in internet explorer 11 the execution is canceled and no error is displayed in the console, it simply never makes the call.

To reduce execution times I am trying to call 1500 records, in google chrome it works perfectly but in internet explorer only makes the first call:

```js
mostrar: function() {
  this.loader = true;

  $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: ('Ajax.asp?rad=' + this.radio1 + '&offsetq=' + this.limit),
    data: 1,
    success: function(e) {

      if (app.radio1 == "0")
        app.programas = e.programas;

      if (e.continuar == "1" && app.radio1 == "1") {
        app.limit = e.conteo;
        console.log(app.limit);

        console.log("va a continuar");
        //  app.programas = (e.programas);    

        app.mostrar();
      }

      app.loader = false;
    },
    failure: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      app.loader = false;
    }
  });
}
```

I'm using vue.js, but I make the calls using Jquery, because axios presents incompatibility with internet explorer 11, currently this code works in chrome, edge, mozilla firefox.

In chrome he makes the calls correctly and in Internet explorer he only makes a call:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBdi9.png (chrome)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7mKL.png (Internet Explorer)

Comment: Is the query cancelled immediately or after some period?

Comment: The first time it runs, however the following times it does not, this only happens in internet explorer.

Comment: So only the first call works? Looks like caching issue - try with `headers: { Pragma: "no-cache", "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }`

Comment: I updated the publication with the two images where it is evident that in chrome it makes the calls correctly and in the internet explorer only makes a cal: https://i.imgur.com/C5wjbBc.png (chrome)  https://i.imgur.com/Jk4F7Tj.png (Internet Explorer)

Comment: Seems that chrome image is described as IE and the opposite. Have you tried setting request headers as advised?

Comment: Yes, add the following code:

-------------------------------------------------------------------
  $.ajax({
 
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {  "Cache-Control": "no-cache" },
                type: 'POST',
                url: ('Ajax.asp?rad=' + this.radio1 + '&offsetq=' + this.limit + '&rndm=' + random),
                success: function (e) {

-----------------------------------------------------------
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, could you show screenshot from Network tab ("Red" in your case) from IE console with visible headers for cancelled request?

Comment: thank you very much,these are the screenshots:

Request headers:
https://i.imgur.com/jcocHo3.png 
 
Response headers:

https://i.imgur.com/0CwUCZ9.png

Comment: Your server response contains `Cache-Control: no-cache, private` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Cacheability so it actually can use private cache

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the error was in the data of the database, a problem when the UTF - 8 Characters were printed from the ajax in internet explorer.

I had to create a function in SQL, to clean the data and now it works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fix `contentType` and `data` will fix your problem. Try to execute `$.ajax` with that parameters:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: ('Ajax.asp?rad=' + this.radio1 + '&offsetq=' + this.limit),
  data: {},
  ...
});
```

FYI: if you don't need to send any data to server, maybe better use `GET` instead of `POST`